# "Cannot find module" error when running jest test

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, jestjs

I have react application that use Milkdown editor. I would like to test this application using jest. Whenever I run jest test that imports Milkdown modules I got following error:

`Cannot find module '@milkdown/core' from 'src/MilkdownEditor.tsx'`

I think the problem is related to the fact that `@milkdown/core` is an esm module.

Could someone help me to understand how I should configure jest in this particular case.

Current jest configuration:

```
import type { Config } from 'jest'

const config: Config = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
  injectGlobals: true,
}

export default config
```

Sample test:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import MilkdownEditor from '../src/MilkdownEditor'

test('test milkdown editor', () => {
  render(<MilkdownEditor />)
})
```

I [created minimal project that reproduces the issue](https://github.com/pawelkorus/demo-jest-milkdown)

I've already tried to apply some suggestions (mostly related to configuring babel), but nothing helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some further examination I came up with two solutions to this problem:

**Solution 1**

As suggested in [jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules) using `--experimental-vm-modules` works fine. For this to work following `jest.config.js` is required:

```js
import type { Config } from 'jest'

const config: Config = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/default-esm',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
  injectGlobals: true,
}

export default config
```

and to make it easier to run tests following npm script in `script` section of `package.json` can be defined:

```json
"scripts": {
  "test": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--experimental-vm-modules jest"
},
```

[Full implementation of this solution](https://github.com/pawelkorus/demo-jest-milkdown/tree/solution/experimental-vm-modules)

**Solution 2**

This solution base on babel `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs`. This is common solution that can be found around. However, in this particular scenario additional module name mapping in jest configuration (`moduleNameMapper`) is required. For now I can't explain what is the reason for this. Additionally, it is necessary to apply babel transformations to `node_modules` which is done by overriding `transformIgnorePatters`. So `jest.config.js` looks as follows:

```js
import type { Config } from 'jest'

const config: Config = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.[t]sx?$": "ts-jest",
    "^.+\\.[j]sx?$": "babel-jest"
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
  ],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "^@milkdown/prose/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/@milkdown/prose/lib/$1.js",
    "^@milkdown/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/@milkdown/$1"
  },
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
  injectGlobals: true,
}

export default config
```

below content of `babel.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"
  ]
}
```

[Full implementation for this solution](https://github.com/pawelkorus/demo-jest-milkdown/tree/solution/babel)